# Expectation Number of Attempts in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

Suppose that we are trying to finish a task and the probability that we can **successfully** finish it is 0.8. Each time we try to finish the task, we call it an attempt. For example, I know that the probability of finishing the task in at most 2 steps is:
0.8 + 0.2*0.8,
but my question is what is the expected number of attempts to finish the task?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: You seem to know how to compute the probability of finishing on the $k$th step; call this $p_k$. Then the expectation is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty kp_k$. Use what you know about geometric series to help compute this series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denoting the attempts needed by $X$, the expectation is found by the summation:
\begin{equation}
E[X] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\cdot(0.2)^{n-1}(0.8) = 0.8\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\cdot(0.2)^{n-1}
\end{equation}
To evaluate the sum, let's take a look at the infinite geometric series:
\begin{align}
S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}
\newline
\frac{d}{dx} S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^{n-1} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x}= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}
In our case, $x=0.2 \Longrightarrow E[X] = 0.8\cdot{\frac{1}{0.8^2}} = 1.25$